# read the file inside a jar but then can not delete it

Tags: java, jar

my thread will read the class data from a jar file, another thread will modify or delete the jar file. the order is read first then delete, but it didn't work, seem that cann't release the resource after reading, how could I reach out?

```
InputStream is = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
try {
URL res = new URL(**file**);
is = res.openStream();
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 10];
int readBytes;

while ((readBytes = bis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    baos.write(bytes, 0, readBytes);
}
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
     bis.close();
     is.close();

return b;
} catch (Exception ex) {
throw ex;
}
```

the parameter "file" is a String like this "jar:file:///C:/Users/HJ16748/Desktop/test.jar!/com/services/plugin/test/Test.class"

Answer (score 0):

Add a finally to your try catch block and close the resources there. Let two threads name be Read and Modify.

Inside Modify thread before deleting or modifying jar add line like this.

```
try{
System.out.println("Waiting for read to finish");
read.thread.join();
}catch(InterruptedException e){
System.out.println("not able to join");//oops catch
}
//codes to delete or modify jar
```

thread called with read is the Thread object

Comment: actually I used the finally block to close the resources, it didn't work yet. just for pretty look here, replaced the finally block.

Comment: I understand you use two threads, One reads data from a file inside jar (which I never thought of since .jar is itself a file) the second thread deletes the jar file itself. _I don't understand what you are achieving here!_ so now check if the first thread is stopped

Comment: Since you have not mention thread name I assume two read & modify. Inside modify thread before executing delete or modify on jar try the edited answer

Comment: thanks shivaharikumar, maybe I've fixed this issue. In the beginning I iterate the exactly class that I wanted in the jar, then return the class location (jar:file:///C:/Users/HJ16748/Desktop/test.jar!/com/services/plugin/test/Test.class) in a method. In another method read the class byte data just you can see above, didn't close the resource, maybe because I didn't close the ZipFile (use the object to iterate all entry in the jar). I changed the code like below, it works correct now.

Answer (score 0):

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(entry);
file = file.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
ZipEntry zipEntry = zf.getEntry(file);

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(zf.getInputStream(zipEntry));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 10];
int readBytes;

while ((readBytes = bis.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    baos.write(bytes, 0, readBytes);
}
b = baos.toByteArray();

baos.close();
bis.close();
zf.close();
```